# c++ monitoring specific pattern into specific line into logfile

Tags: c++, mysql

I am developing a small program to monitor a log file, this program should find lines that contain a specific text "LOGFAC", when that specific text is found on the line it must separate portions (the content of ARG1 and ARG2) from that text to do update this information in a mysql database on localhost. Currently I can read the lines from the log file, but I do not have enough knowledge to complete the other necessary operations. I really need a lot of help. Thank you in advance!

Program usage:  #monitor.prog logfile

====== start exemple.log

> Line1 someinfo... LOGFAC someinfo... ARG1=myarg1
>   someinfo...ARG2=myarg2 Line2 someinfo... LOGFAC someinfo...
>   ARG1=myarg1 someinfo...ARG2=myarg2 Line3 someinfo... LOGFAC
>   someinfo... ARG1=myarg1 someinfo...ARG2=myarg2

====== end exemple.log
====== start monitor.cpp

```
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include  <string>
 using namespace std;     
 using std :: string;    
  int main ()     {     
  int ch;        
     while (true) {    
             if ((ch = cin.get ())! = EOF) {    
                     cout << (char) ch;    
             }    
             else {    
                     usleep (1000000);    
                     // cout << "wait a second .." << endl;    
                     cin.clear ();    
             }    
     }     
  }
```

====== end monitor.cpp

Comment: It doesn't look like you tried much.  First, I would read in a line at a time into a std::string.  Then you can use the find member function of std::string to find your starting and ending points of what you want to extract.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip my friend, but I'm an apprentice and I do not know how to do what you said. could you post an example? Thank you.

Comment: search this site with "c++ read file by line" and the first answer will show you what to do.